# How to change view value when scope model changes

Tags: angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

Am working on an app that uses a comment system. After a user must have finished reading an article there's a comment button which takes him to a different view where to add comment and submit. The issue is that the article's view and comment's view use same controller but different views. Now how will I increase the comment count on the article's view once the user's comment is successfully sent and the scope model holding the comment count value increments cos this does not also reflect on the comment count view when the user clicks back to return to the article's page. In the article's page I have:
    {{$scope.comment_count}}
While in the controller for both views(different states) I have:
    $scope.comment_count = response.date.comment_count;

The issue is that the value of $scope.comment_count changes(increments by 1 thus:$scope.comment_count++) while the user is in the comment page(different view and state).

Comment: Can you show me your view and controller page?

Comment: @cfprabhu I have done that.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the problem in a codepen?